# How to sort by name and surname from MySql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I know I can do this `"SELECT * FROM members WHERE isHere = 0 ORDER BY surname"` to get the members that aren't here from my database and sort them. However if their surnames are the same I want to sort them by name. Any tips on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ORDER BY multiple columns. Like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE isHere = 0 
ORDER BY surname ASC, name ASC;
```

> You can sort on multiple columns, and you can sort different columns
>   in different directions, which means you can sort the result-set by ASC where as name by DESC.
>   Which is not required in your case but just for info.

---

Default sorting will be in case-insensitive fashion. If you want case-sensitive sort for a column, add a **BINARY** keyword for a column.

Like this,

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE isHere = 0 
ORDER BY BINARY surname ASC, name ASC;
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html

Comment: True that, added. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use multiple `ORDER BY` clauses to use multiple sorting options:

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE isHere = 0 
ORDER BY surname ASC,
name ASC
```

This will sort by surname first and, if two or more users have the same surname, you can then sort them by name. If you wanted to, you can add a thirds sort to sort by age as well.

```
SELECT * 
FROM members 
WHERE isHere = 0 
ORDER BY surname ASC,
name ASC,
age DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want name first and then surname use like this

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE isHere = 0 ORDER BY name asc,surname asc;
```

If you want surname first and then ame use like this

```
SELECT * FROM members WHERE isHere = 0 ORDER BY surname asc,name asc;
```

change `asc` and `desc` according to sorting by